# Jquery/Cheerio: push content between tags to JSON via loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Trying to put the data from a dozen of similar webpages to JSON. The structure of page is defined but the amount of each block may vary:

```html
<h2>Block1</h2>
 <p><strong>Title1</strong></p>
  <p>content</p>
  
  <!–– the amount of p with content may vary ––>
  
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
 
 <!–– the amount of p with highlighted title may vary ––>
 
 <p><strong>Title_N</strong></p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
 
<!–– the amount of h2 blocks may vary ––>
 
<h2>Block_N</h2>
 <p><strong>Other_Title</strong></p>
  <p>content</p>
```

I was trying to form a JSON like below, but having trouble to iterate through tags - between tags - between tags when they are on the same level of hierarchy and their amount is uncertain:

```
result.push({ 
BlockName: $('.frame h2').text(),
BlockContent:[{
    TitleName1: $('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(1)').text(),
        TitleContent1[{
            Content1:$('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(1)').nextUntil($('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(2)')).each(///),
            Content2:$('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(2)').nextUntil($('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(3)')).each(///)),
            ///
            ContentN:$('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(Last-1)').nextUntil($('.frame p>strong:nth-of-class(LastOne)')).each(///),
                    }],
            ///     
            }],
        })
```

So I can't even specify until exact what tag should I gather the data for each entry. Is there a way without storing the indexes of all tags in a respective variables?

For example - lower the hierarchy of some entries in created flat JSON: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iryba.png)

What approach should I try?

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a dirty example you can take inspiration from, the output variable should fit your specs!

I used js to iterate through all nodes of the DOM and determined if it was the name of a block, a title or content using the type of the node (`HTMLParagraphElement` and such).

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(dom.children).forEach((node) => {
  if (node instanceof HTMLHeadingElement) {
    if (Object.keys(currentBlock).length !== 0) {
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7dmwd7d/

Comment: Wow! Thank you, works like a charm! Also the code looks so modern. Will try to implement this approach instead of way dirtier indented list of mine.

Comment: Hello, dear MRousse,
Is there a way to use the code you've provided on a local html file with node.js? I'm using jsdom to access dom tree, but code parts like `if (node instanceof HTMLHeadingElement) {` still won't run. Keeps saying `HTMLHeadingElement is not defined`

Sorry for bother.

Comment: Hi @A.Howe, a good enough proxy would be to verify against the tagname, so:
`if (node.tagname === 'H1') {`